# How to avoid print footer in last page of JasperReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

As the title suggests, is it possible to avoid printing the page footer on last page of the report? Right now I can only avoid printing footer on first page like so:

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} > 1
```

I also want this footer to be hidden on last page of report. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a last page footer add that

Comment: I didn't know that the lastPageFooter band exists. this really helped me out. Thank you!